# Can't type/view bold text in Android Facebook Messenger App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

I have been building a Messenger Bot for about a week now and I had no problems so far. But recently I got stuck in an absurd bug (kind of).

So I use bold text in certain parts of my messages like `*bold text*` (which translates to **bold text**) and it works perfectly fine in desktop version of Facebook and also on messenger.com but strangely the android messenger app can't display the text between the asterisks in bold, instead, it just prints out `*bold text*`

Below are the screenshots to better represent the issue

### messenger.com screenshot

[image: Messenger.com screenshot]

### Android Messenger App Screenshot

[image: Android Messenger App Screenshot]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It is working fine on the facebook bot of World Health Organization. Of course. mobile version, but I still don't know what is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown formatting of text isn't officially supported, so it works sporadically depending on the platform Messenger is being run on.

Comment: But this essentially degrades the user experience as the pattern is which the information is displayed varies from platform to platform. Also even if it isn't officially supported, it works in the web versions of Facebook then (practically) it should work in the mobile apps too.

Answer (score 1):

The official help page does indeed state that it only works for computers: https://www.facebook.com/help/147348452522644

> Keep in mind that text formatting is only visible on a computer, and will not appear in the Messenger app on mobile.

However, it seems like they've started testing it on mobile:
https://twitter.com/wongmjane/status/1098658053426098176

[image: Twitter screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Can resolve with this simple hack

1. convert your text using some online unicode text converters (e.g: https://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi)
2. copy converted text and paste into your code. That's it.

This is working in facebook.com, messenger.com and messenger mobile app.